# How to get the filtered records which are not in another table

Tags: sql-server

I am using the below query to retrieve the records from External_Blk_Itm_Contracts Table.

So here in BudContractSummary table I have TankId and ContractId.

So here I want retrieve all records from External_Blk_Itm_Contracts table and condition is  same TankId and contractId should not be in BudContractSummary Table

But can be different combinations. But not same combination

how can i do this

```
    SELECT  BTANK.TANKID, BCON.CONTRACTID FROM External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC
INNER JOIN BUDTERMINALS BT ON BT.MBFTERMINALNAME = EBIC.TerminalName
INNER JOIN BudCustomers BC ON BC.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName
INNER JOIN BUDCONTRACTS BCON ON BCON.CONTRACTNAME = EBIC.ContractName AND BCON.TERMINALID = BT.TERMINALID AND BCON.CUSTOMERID = BC.CustomerID
INNER JOIN BUDTANKS BTANK ON BTANK.TERMINALID = BT.TERMINALID 
LEFT JOIN BudContractSummary BCS ON BCS.TankID = BTANK.TANKID AND BCS.ContractID = BCON.CONTRACTID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get records that are NOT in BudContractSummary with the same TankID and ContractID, add a WHERE condition that looks for BCS.TankID IS NULL, like so:

```
WHERE BCS.TankID IS NULL
```

Since you've done a left join on that table using both TankID  and ContractID, the WHERE condition will eliminate those records from your result set.

Comment: so just to check tank id is null or do i need to check both tank and contractid is null?

Comment: you want to check a field that always has a value in BudContractSummary.  i'm assuming both tankid and contractid always have a value, and in that case, you can use either field in the where condition.  it's not necessary to use both.